# How to group all tf.summary in tensorboard

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I have a number of `tf.summary` writes throughout my graph to visualize the weights, gradients, etc. at various points. However, these are really cluttering my graph as they all show up individually (ie. zero_fraction_1, zero_fraction_2, etc.) -- is there any way to combine these so that they are grouped together in a node in tensorboard? Consider the following code:

```
for v in tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, scope=scope):
        tf.summary.histogram("{}/weight_histogram".format(v.name), v)
        tf.summary.scalar("{}/weight_sparsity".format(v.name), tf.nn.zero_fraction(v))
```

I would like to make it so that each tf.nn.zero_fraction does not result in an individual node in tensorboard.  Any suggested approaches?